# Mutate property in object array F#

Tags: ios, arrays, f#, xamarin

I have an array of type UIView in F# initialized like this:

```
let mutable views = Array.init 100 (fun x -> new UIView())
```

I want to change the property named BackgroundColor in each view, so I have this:

```
views |> Array.iter (fun (x:UIView) -> (x.BackgroundColor <- UIColor.Blue))
```

But this isn't changing the property.  What am I missing?  This is Xamarin iOS F# btw.

Answer (score 0):

Guess i asked too soon.  The answer is not to annotate the type x in the anonymous function.  so doing this:

```
views 
|> Array.iter (fun x -> x.BackgroundColor <- UIColor.Blue) 
|> this.View.AddSubViews
```

is done

Comment: This is ugly because if the argument you're passing to `AddSubViews` is just unit then say so: `this.View.AddSubViews()`.

Comment: but it's not, so i don't